# Cluster/partition by time

Tags: time-series, clustering, kernel-smoothing, partitioning

I have a dataset of different events in time. I want to group/cluster/partition the data by datetime. A small example of the time of the data might be:

[19-09-2018 12:00, 19-09-2018 12:01, 19-09-2018 12:02, 19-09-2018 12:30, 19-09-2018 12:31, 19-09-2018 12:31]

Which I want to cluster as:

[[19-09-2018 12:00, 19-09-2018 12:01, 19-09-2018 12:02],[ 19-09-2018 12:30, 19-09-2018 12:31, 19-09-2018 12:31]]

Please note that the size of the cluster can vary a lot in size. Some clusters might contain 1 event, while others might contain 100 events. A window will not suffice, because sometimes events happen successively for 2 minutes, while other times they will happen successively for 30 minutes.

I am no expert on clustering, so I don't really know where to look. At the moment I am looking into Kernel Density Estimation, to partition the data by the local minima.

My question is:
How to partition the data by time?

Or maybe more specific: How to use Kernel Density Estimation on time series data?